# Is there a function to replace several symbols with one in Python?

Tags: python

For example, I have a string

```
"ac----cs-------aacv"
```

I need to get a string like

```
"ac-cs-acv"
```

Can it be done with a built-in function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A regular expression that matches one or more `-` and replaces it with `-` using [`re.sub()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub) is a simple way to day this:

```
import re

s =  "ac----cs-------aacv"    
re.sub(r'-+', '-', s)
# 'ac-cs-aacv'
```

If you want to replace *every* duplicate character, you can adjust the regex and replace with the captured group. `(.)\1+` will duplicates and then replace them with the captured character with `r'\1'`:

```
import re

s =  "ac----cs-------aacv"        
re.sub(r'(.)\1+', r'\1', s)
# 'ac-cs-acv'
```

Comment: What about `'aacv'` ?

Comment: OP's example doesn't only eliminate repeating `'-'` but any repeating characters, such as `'aa'`.

Comment: Oh, thanks @PaulPanzer — I didn't notice that in the output of the example. I've added an option if that's what the OP is after.

Answer (score 1):

`itertools.groupby` groups repeats:

```
import itertools as it

list(it.groupby("ac----cs-------aacv"))
# [('a', <itertools._grouper object at 0x7fd6c31bff28>), ('c', <itertools._grouper object at 0x7fd6c3423e80>), ('-', <itertools._grouper object at 0x7fd6c3423e10>), ('c', <itertools._grouper object at 0x7fd6c3423f28>), ('s', <itertools._grouper object at 0x7fd6c3423f98>), ('-', <itertools._grouper object at 0x7fd6c3423e48>), ('a', <itertools._grouper object at 0x7fd6c3423eb8>), ('c', <itertools._grouper object at 0x7fd6c13c9ef0>), ('v', <itertools._grouper object at 0x7fd6c13c95c0>)]
```

It also keeps the repeating elements in a `_grouper` object which here we do not need.

One way of getting rid of those:

```
"".join(k for k,g in it.groupby("ac----cs-------aacv"))
# 'ac-cs-acv'
```

Another:

```
"".join(next(zip(*it.groupby("ac----cs-------aacv"))))
# 'ac-cs-acv'
```